# How to update variable from with if statement MQL5

Tags: c#, c++, if-statement, scope, mql5

I have been googling for two days now, but can't figure this out and it seems to be basic.

Within the `void OnTick()`, I would like to create a variable `int a;`. Lets say it starts out with no value `int a;`, then I test condition if `a` is `NULL` or `||` equals `1` like this `if (a == NULL || a == 1)` which should always return true the first time the `if` statement runs due to `NULL`. I then assign a value to the variable `a = 0;`, so now `a` should equal 0.

This should trigger the `else if(a == 0)` the next time `OnTick()` is called, at this point I assign `a = 1;` resulting in the `if` being triggered next time round, etc and infinitum, constantly checking and assigning values switching between 0 and 1.

```
void OnTick()
int a;
if (PositionsTotal() < 1)
{
    if(a == NULL || a == 1)
    {         
        a = 0;                                    
    }
    else if(a == 0) 
    {
        a = 1;                    
    }
}
```

I do not know what is going on, but during Testing in Strategy tester, I am getting a long string of numbers which switches between negatives and positives always with the same number `-123456789` or `123456789`, always 9 digits long.

Or during Debugging from Meta Editor. A random positive 3 digit number which never changes!
So far I have had both 303 and 597.

Beyond frustrating and most likely answered somewhere else.
Just not sure how to phrase the search term.

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you declare your variable `a` inside the method `OnTick`, so it starts with an arbitrary value every time you call this method. Try declaring it outside this method.

Comment: ahahahahah lol like I said brainfart!!! Thanks AbelAziz!! Working perfectly now.